# Order properties in rapidjson output

Tags: c++, rapidjson

What is the best way to change document output for rapidjson? What I want to do is to get all properties in alphabetic order and remove leading spaces in pretty print. It looks like I have to use custom Document and override Accept method. But maybe there is more accurate way to do that?

Comment: "get all properties in alphabetic order " - Why?

Comment: I have about 400Mb json which I want to store in git. In order to reduce git delta size in need predictable properties order. Alphabetic looks the best option for me.